# Объяcнить орфографию

Tags: орфография

Слово немощеный, а конкретно букву щ в корне.

Answer (score 1):

Ст чередуется с Щ: вырастить - выращенный, мостить - мощеный, простить - прощеный

Comment: Можно добавить следующее: чередование СТ/Щ является историческим и отражается на письме, приведенные в качестве примера слова обычно не вызывают затруднений. Проблемы начинаются тогда, когда приходится отличать историческое чередование от фонетического, например в словах "брусчатый" (фон. чер.) и "дощатый" (истор. чер.), которые произносятся одинаково.